# Tailwindcss does not automatically reflect the changes in the browser

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, tailwind-css, nuxtjs3

Every time that I add a class, to see the changes I have to stop running nuxt, reload the vs code window and run "npm run dev" again. Then I can see the changes

My tailwind.config.js :

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
    content: [
        './components/**/*.{js,vue,ts}',
        './layouts/**/*.vue',
        './pages/**/*.vue',
        './plugins/**/*.{js,ts}',
        './nuxt.config.{js,ts}'
    ],
    theme: {
        extend: {}
    },
    plugins: [require('daisyui')]
}
```

I place the tailwind.css file inside assets/css/tailwind.css

And import it inside my layout component: layouts/default.vue

My nuxt.config.ts:

```js
// https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/configuration/nuxt.config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    css: ['~/assets/css/tailwind.css'],
    build: {
        postcss: {
            postcssOptions: {
                plugins: {
                    tailwindcss: {},
                    autoprefixer: {}
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

My package.json:

```json
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nuxt": "3.0.0-rc.11",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "daisyui": "^2.31.0",
    "firebase": "^9.10.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: The module [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73960936/tailwindcss-does-not-automatically-reflect-the-changes-in-the-browser#comment130601742_73963892) should be working fine with Nuxt3. Give that one a try and comment out `plugins: [require('daisyui')]` first to see when the issue may come from. You should have a properly working thing by default. Also, depending on what you use, you may not need to import the CSS in your default layout at all. Lastly, if you have an HMR issue, you can directly skip a VScode reload, it's not related if running your server in a CLI.

Answer (score 0):

I think Nuxt.js is a framework that makes server-side rendering like NextJs for React.
In that way, all of the data and HTMLis rendered by the Nuxt server, which sends a generated "html/css" package to the client **with only the css class that you used in your code**.
So I would say it's normal to rebuild everytime you want to see your change for the css class you just add.

If you want to see directly the changes without rebuilding each time (like in the browser dev tool in order to write your css class easily), I would advise you to link in the HTML root file (index.html), the complete tailwind css sheet.
You can find a version on the tailwind doc page like this one : https://tailwindcss.com/_next/static/css/b606771d290f9908.css

Then you can remove the link at the end of your dev work.

Comment: I'm using https://tailwindcss.nuxtjs.org/ It' s working so far.

Comment: No, you do have HMR with JIT. You don't need to spam your browser with megabytes of unused code, OP is probably not using Tailwind v1 here, hence this is not the way to go.

Comment: @RicardodePaula you have `tailwindcss` in your `package.json`, nothing related to `@nuxtjs/tailwindcss` so far.

Comment: I uninstalled tailwind and installed Nuxt tailwind. It's not a good idea?

Comment: @RicardodePaula please update your question to reflect your changes so.